# Run Cordova/Phonegap based app on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, samsung-smart-tv

I have an app that is developed based on Cordova/Phonegap. It's purely in Javascript, HTML5 and CSS3. I am able to do small modifications to the present code and was able to run on mobile and Android TV. However, now, I want to run this app on samsung smart TV. I am ready to little modifications to make it run on Samsung TV. In the future, I also want to run it on Philips, LG smart TV's as well.

However, what I don't know is, what to modify? Is there any documentation available from Samsung, Philips and LG on how to port Cordova/Phonegap based apps on to TV? If so please share the knowledge.

Comment: Although this is a useful question, it is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow, and asks for off-site resources. If you're encountering specific problems when porting to one specific platform, that is something we can answer.

Comment: I was only looking for any websites or resources that could guide me how can I approach further with this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go though [samsungdforum](http://www.samsungdforum.com/), there you will have all the info regarding how to start app development for Samsung smart TV, I will suggest download an sample app, look into its code and understand it, then try to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: there is little difference between lg TV and Samsung Tv, But my suggestion is ist learn one smart tv app development then you will easily understand the difference, difference is minor ideally concept is same